# How do I reference a DIM Name (not value) in a function?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Dim` publicly declared in my `Form`, how would I set/change the value of this `Dim` in a function without manually calling it like this: `Test = "New Val"`?

I would need it to be something like this:

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim Test As String = "I do not want to read this value in the function, 
                          I do however need to change this value"

    Private Function PassingDimName(ByVal DimName As dim)
       'Having it like this gives the following error:
       '"Keyword does not name a type"
        DimName = "Dims new value"
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PassingDimName(Test)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a `Dictionary`, not a set of variables.

Comment: `Dim` is not a noun, verb or adjective nor is it a `Type` (`... As Dim`). It's purpose is to *declare* a variable.  *Where* you declare it determines its [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope).  Not sure what you are up to with wanting to change a variable but not "read" it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: also read up on declaring variables in general. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration

Comment: @Plutonix - I do need to read it's value, just not in this function.  It's read by different methods.  My app is based on a lot of user input/customization which are stored in these dim values, having a function like this would reduce the amount of required code in my App making things alot neater/more organised.

Comment: @David I think that'll work for what I need, thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. As is, your question is nearly gibberish (`these Dim values` its still not an adjective, and they are *variables* not values) .   If a variable has form/class level scope, you dont need to pass it in order to "read" or "change" it.

Comment: How do I reference a variable name as a string and not the value of the variable in a function?  Then the answer below works.  If you're just wanting access to the value, to change it, then pass it by Reference, byRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the value of the variable then change your function to this.

```
Private Sub PassingDimName(ByRef DimName As String)
    'Having it like this gives the following error:
    '"Keyword does not name a type"
    DimName = "Dims new value"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Reflection.GetField (String, BindingFlags)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx) to access a field by name

Here are some functions for setting and getting field values:

```
Public Sub SetValue(name As String, value As Object)
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = Me.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    fi.SetValue(Me, value)
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(name As String) As Object
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = Me.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    Return fi.GetValue(Me)
End Function
```

Note: the BindingFlags are specific to your application, where you have declared a private field (`Dim Test As ...`). See [BindingFlags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to use something other than a private field.

In your specific implementation, you could set a new string to the field in the button click like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetValue("Test1", "new value")
End Sub
```

A minimal, complete example to demonstrate how it works could look like this

```
Dim f2 = New Form2()

Console.WriteLine(f2.GetValue("Test1"))
Console.WriteLine(f2.GetValue("Test2"))

f2.SetValue("Test1", "new value")
f2.SetValue("Test2", 1)

Console.WriteLine(f2.GetValue("Test1"))
Console.WriteLine(f2.GetValue("Test2"))
```

with the form

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim Test1 As String = "initial value"
    Dim Test2 As Integer = 0

    Public Sub SetValue(name As String, value As Object)
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = Me.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        fi.SetValue(Me, value)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetValue(name As String) As Object
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = Me.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        Return fi.GetValue(Me)
    End Function

End Class
```

output:

> initial value
>   
> 0
>   
> new value
>   
> 1

Another note: when setting the field, you aren't guaranteed to know the type. Trying `f2.SetValue("Test2", "new value")` would compile but would fail at runtime when trying to convert a string to an integer. If you know all your fields are strings, then it may be better to declare `Public Sub SetValue(name As String, value As String)` and `Public Function GetValue(name As String) As String` with the appropriate casts.

Comment: The guy doesn't know how to declare a variable, and you send an answer to use reflection? :)